# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Comment.deferred_id' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, web-applications

So I am pretty new to this and I am creating a web application with Cakephp framework and a MySQL database. I had a column in my "Comment" table called deferred_id which referenced the id in my deferred table. I changed the name of it from deferred_id to form_id in the comment table and changed it everywhere within my code as well but now I am getting an error when I try to test my application:

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Comment.deferred_id' in 'field list'

Not sure what the problem is because deferred_id doesn't exist in the Comment table anymore. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Hard to tell without any code.

Comment: One possibility is that you have a view that references the view through `select *`.  When the view is created it gets expanded with the fields at that time.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of code guys. I just wasn't sure where the problem would be so didn't know what to share. I did find my problem however. I just had some inconsistencies between the way my foreign keys were set up in the database and within my cakephp models. All fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on the debug level in config/core.php so that the cache gets cleared. Cakephp store the queries in cache. That is why the query is picking up the old column name.

Comment: I looked into it and it appeared that the debug level was already set to level 2. I figured out that my problem was some inconsistencies with setting up my foreign keys. Thanks for your input