# cakephp query referring to deleted column

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have a strange problem where a column I deleted from a table is still being referred to in a query.

I deleted the field (column) change_pending from the monitors table and checked that it is not referred to in my code.

The web pages are working OK but this is some batch processing in a console.  Is it possible the fields (columns) have been cached for the model?

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Monitor.change_pending' in 'field list'
#0 D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SRP\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(458): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SRP\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(424): DboSource->_execute('SELECT `Monitor...', Array)
#2 D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SRP\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(665): DboSource->execute('SELECT `Monitor...', Array, Array)
#3 D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SRP\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(1077): DboSource->fetchAll('SELECT `Monitor...', false)
#4 D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SRP\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php(2900): DboSource->read(Object(AppModel), Array)
#5 D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SRP\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php(2872): Model->_readDataSource('all', Array)
#6 D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SRP\app\Console\Command\ProcessRequestShell.php(122): Model->find('all', Array)
#7 D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SRP\app\Console\Command\ProcessRequestShell.php(241): ProcessRequestShell->complete_requests()
#8 D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SRP\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php(434): ProcessRequestShell->main()
#9 D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SRP\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(207): Shell->runCommand(NULL, Array)
#10 D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SRP\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(66): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#11 D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SRP\lib\Cake\Console\cake.php(49): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#12 {main}
42S22
```

Comment: This post sounds similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848607/column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-comment-deferred-id-in-field-list/16850925#16850925

Comment: I set the "AppName/app/Config/core.php" debug level to 2 and it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you clear your model cache, it stores your DB schema in there for speed.

```
 /var/www/mysite/app/tmp/cache/models
```

That will negate the need to have to set `debug` to 2.